# Add custom checkout fields below the terms and conditions in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, checkout

I have built an e-commerce site using Woocommerce. I would like to add two more check boxes below the terms and conditions. I have searched everywhere for a working solution and the only thing that I found is a commercial plugin.

How to add custom checkout fields (2 checkboxes) below the terms and conditions programmatically?

Location of the terms and condition screenshot:

[image: The two checkboxes below the terms and conditions]

Comment: I do not think PHP is the solution. You may be able to alter the template of the terms. You should take a look at where this content comes from and try to override the template. If it is not in a template, it may be connected to a 'hook'.

Comment: I looked on the internet and saw that there was a way to add it in the template which i did but it didnt work.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yeah I have just done that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The 1st hooked function displays the 2 additional checkout fields
- The 2nd hooked function will check that both checkboxes are "selected" to allow checkout, displaying a custom error notice if not…

The code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_terms_and_conditions', 'checkout_additional_checkboxes');
function checkout_additional_checkboxes( ){
    $checkbox1_text = __( "My first checkbox text", "woocommerce" );
    $checkbox2_text = __( "My Second checkbox text", "woocommerce" );
    ?>
    <p class="form-row custom-checkboxes">
        <label class="woocommerce-form__label checkbox custom-one">
            <input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" name="custom_one" > <span><?php echo  $checkbox1_text; ?></span> <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <label class="woocommerce-form__label checkbox custom-two">
            <input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" name="custom_two" > <span><?php echo  $checkbox2_text; ?></span> <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
    </p>
    <?php
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['custom_one'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You must accept "My first checkbox".' ), 'error' );
    if ( ! $_POST['custom_two'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You must accept "My second checkbox".' ), 'error' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).*

Tested and works.

[image]

[image]